# Crash When load a Custom NSBundle

Tags: ios, crash, nsbundle

Hi All,I've a problem when I load a Custom `NSBundle`(**TicketBooking.bundle**), the APP crash
(`exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9 EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)`).

The most strange thing is this:
1. When I connect the iPhone 4 to Mac ,run the APP from `Xcode`, call method `[TicketBooking load]` or `[TicketBooking principalClass]`, it returns the right data, APP runs OK;
2. Then I disconnect the iPhone 4 with Mac, press the APP, when run at method `[TicketBooking load]` or `[TicketBooking principalClass]`, the APP crashes immediately;

PS:TicketBooking.bundle contains only two classes, `CO_ManageVC.h` and `CO_ManageVC.m`,

CO_ManageVC.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CO_ManageVC : UIViewController

- (NSString *)TestWithKey:(NSString *)key;

@end
```

CO_ManageVC.m:

```
- (NSString *)TestWithKey:(NSString *)key{
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"tinln"])
        return @"CN_North";
    else {
        NSLog(@"Get CONamePrefix error:Wrong key");
        return nil;
}
```

when I call:

```
NSBundle *TBBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/TicketBooking.bundle"]];
//    NSLog(@"%@",[NSBundle allBundles]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[TBBundle infoDictionary]);
    if (TBBundle)
        NSLog(@"打开-done");
    else {
        NSLog(@"打开-fail");
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"ready crash");
    //        [TBBundle load];  //disconnect and run,crash here
    Class TBClass = [TBBundle principalClass];   //disconnect and run,crash here
//        Class TBClass = [TBBundle classNamed:@"CO_ManageVC"]; ////disconnect and run,crash here
    UIViewController *tempVC = [[TBClass alloc] init];
    NSString *COStr = [tempVC performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"TestWithKey:") withObject:@"tinln"];
    NSLog(@"data：%@",COStr);    //when connect and run with xcode, NSLog return:data：CN_North
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tempVC animated:YES];
    [tempVC release];
```

Comment: Bundles are not meant to be used like this in iOS applications.  What is it that you are trying to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: It's a kind of design pattern，it's helpful of module partition，we use bundle in Mac OS APP,and it's works fine,think about it:You can update one module of your APP with few seconds,or you can choose update your APP in APP Store for about seven days,which one you will choice?

Comment: Right, that pattern makes sense on a platform where dynamic linking is allowed.  However, dynamic linking is not available for user applications on iOS so this pattern is impossible.  `NSBundle` is really a remnant of Cocoa and OS X.  Even the documentation hasn't been well updated.  Also if you are trying to download them from the server and bypass the review (as it seems you are) then you are violating the app store rules.

Comment: Thank you borrrden，you're right，iOS load code in custom NSBundle is forbidden。maybe it's a kind of code access security in iOS，I really like bundle，it's amazing。